# Using a button to add a jPanel over a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, jpanel

I've been looking for a while and I can't find an helpful answer for my problem.

I'm using the Netbeans GUI Builder but right now I'm stuck: my intention is to use a button to make visible a jPanel object.

I've tried to directly insert this jPanel inside the JFrame (leaving it not visible until the button is pressed). The thing is, I could access the jPanel without the need of pressing the button: the panel wasn't visible but I could access the textfield if I tried to click over the blank space the panel is supposed to appear onto.

So now I have a separated class jPanel1 but I don't know how to add it to the JFrame.
This is the code I'm using for my button

```
  private void modifyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    JPanel newpanel=new modifyUserData(this.thisUser);
    this.getContentPane().add(newpanel);
    newpanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

but when I run it and press the button I get an "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Any ideas?

Comment: all JComponents excluding Top-Level Containers are visible by default, exception is form??? JPanel newpanel=new modifyUserData(this.thisUser); or from elsewhere, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, look into `CardLayout`.